# Error carga de Formulario Domicilio pattern html5 php

Tags: php, html5, formularios

Hola tengo una campo de un formulario que es de tipo Domicilio.
O sea debo permitir letras y numeros:
 el campo es asi

```
 <input type="text" 
    required pattern="[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1](\s*[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1]*)*[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1][0-9]{2,254}"class="form-control" name="Domicilio" title="Domicilio del postulante." id="Domicilio" placeholder="Direccion" required>
```

el tema es que pongo:
San Martin 245
y no lo toma
Estuve buscando como resolverlo, pero no pude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo que se me ocurrió es acortar un poco la expresión regular, que acepte texto con espacios y limitar ese texto de `2` a `249` y limitar los números de `2` a `5`.

Expresión regular:

```
([a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1\s]{2,249})+([0-9]{2,5})
```

Ejemplo input:

```
<input type="text" pattern="([a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1\s]{2,249})+([0-9]{2,5})" class="form-control" name="Domicilio" title="Domicilio del postulante." id="Domicilio" placeholder="Direccion" required>
```

(Ví que tenias el atributo required repetido en el input)

Espero que te sea algo de utilidad.

Comment: Excelente..!!!!!!!!!Gracias Jonas